# How does the Wind Demon's Arrow Bane ability (from the Creature Codex) interact with the rogue's Sneak Attack feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage, rogue, sneak-attack

*Creature Codex for 5th Edition is a non WoTC bestiary written by Kobold Press with over 400 new foes.*

The [Wind Demon](https://www.5esrd.com/database/creature/demon-wind/) (*Creature Codex*, p. 93) has an ability called "Arrow Bane", which states:

> When the wind demon is targeted by an attack or spell that requires a ranged attack roll, roll a d6. On a 1 to 5, the attacker has disadvantage on the attack roll. On a 6, the wind demon is unaffected, and the attack is reflected back at the attacker as though it originated from the wind demon, turning the attacker into the target.

How do you think this would interact with the rogue's Sneak Attack feature? Should the extra damage be applied?

PS: I'm aware that Creature Codex is not official. Nevertheless, I would like to have some other GMs opinions' about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There won't be any Sneak Attack when an attack is deflected

Regardless of who is considered to be the "attacker" when an attack is reflected back on the Rogue, which is indeed ambiguous due to how its worded, there isn't going to be any Sneak Attack.

If the Demon is the attacker, it doesn't have Sneak Attack, so it can't add any.

If the Rogue is the attacker, it *can* add Sneak Attack damage *when it hits*. Since the Rogue already knows they've become the target by the time they roll to hit, they're not going to add Sneak Attack to their attack against themselves.

> Sneak Attack
>
> Beginning at 1st Level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe's distraction. Once per turn, you **can** deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an Attack (...)

The same thing will apply to Smite, Maneuvers, or any other optional thing that happens when you hit. Non-optional effects will happen.

In the case of the attack not deflecting, it's made with Disadvantage, so there won't be any sneak attack either.

Comment: Are you saying the rogue attacking the Demon gets to use Sneak Attack?  Immediately after the part you quote it says "if you have advantage on the attack roll", so if the rogue requires advantage, and the Demon can only be hit with disadvantage, how is there ever a sneak attack?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant when it's a deflection. Let me clarify.

Answer (score 3):

To me the interaction with sneak attack would be

- On a 1-5, no sneak attack damage is awarded (as the attack is done with disadvantage, hence no sneak attack). This case doesn’t appear to be the one you’re unclear about, correct me if I’m wrong here.
- On a 6, no sneak attack damage is awarded, as (presumably) the Wind Demon doesn't have sneak attack, and "as though it originated from the wind demon" reads to me that any sneak attack damage bonus in this situation would have to come from the demon.

This ability is very ambiguously worded (for sake of brevity, I assume) and an unfortunate hodgepodge of attack roll manipulation and damage roll manipulation that don’t go together well.

On a side note: I think the ability is impractical to some degree. A lot of players roll attack rolls and damage die simulataneausly, and this ability is even more confusing then. The damage manipulation aspects are not limited to sneak attack, either; imagine your tiefling rogue with their fire resistance attacks with their flame tongue sword, for example.

I personally would've preferred if either only attack rolls or only damage rolls were affected, e.g.

*After rolling damage dice, roll 1d6. On a 1, 2, 3 the damage is dealt normally. On a 4, 5, prevent the damage. On a 6, instead deal the damage to the attacking character.*

seems to me much clearer with a similar effect.

Comment: Could you explain why you believe this ruling is correct?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Mostly the phrase  "as though it originated from the wind demon". I think it is badly (imprecisely/ambiguously) worded for the sake of brevity, which is a mistake in this instance I would say. Actually, any and all damage-manipulating abilities of both the demon and the player character would be somewhat ambiguous here at least as far as I can see. That's why I like my example abilities wording a lot more.

Comment: That sort of explanation I think would be helpful for the answer. Right now it mostly reads like "here's what I think", with no support given for why what you think is correct. I think I probably agree with your ruling, but I'd like to see the reasoning spelled out more clearly, probably by explaining how the relevant rules work together.

Comment: I have the same understanding about it not be a sneak attack because it originates from the demon, but it the other hand, a critical attack will remain a critical because its just reflecting the attack per se. This is a passive effect, the demon does not "make aim" or so, it just "copy and paste" the attack back to the rogue, hence, it leaves margin for other interpretations if an sneak attack would be applied. But i agree with you.